# Generate GUID in Windows with batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, guid

How can I generate a GUID in a batch file running using the commandline in Windows?

Comment: There is no built-in command available that does that. Either write your own, or get an existing one.

Comment: BTW, MS-DOS has been dead for at least 10 years. The program that runs batch files is the command prompt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569858/command-line-guid-for-unix-and-windows

Comment: @Tim Robinson : Thanks for your input, looking forward for help on creating GUIDs.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The Windows SDK comes with a tool called `uuidgen` (if you have Visual Studio, you'll have the Windows SDK, and you need to run the [Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx) to set proper paths).

```
C:\>uuidgen
```

This will output a new GUID, e.g.

> cc23b318-156e-473f-aa6e-517bf091a0f0

Comment: Maybe download and install the Windows SDK separately? Although it's a lot for one utility - it would be quicker to write your own than to wait for the download.

Comment: incases where i can't download due to some reasons what can be another alternative than SDK

Comment: If you have no other alternative you'll probably need to write your own GUID generator

Comment: You need to use the -c option on uuidgen for a windows installer project file.

Comment: Funny thing, I have three different versions of VS but uuidgen was not in the `PATH` for me. Also, it doesn't seem to be really random but time-based (Unix versions of this utility have a `-r` and `-t` flags to specify if you want it random-based or time-based.

Comment: Can I store it on a batch variable?

Comment: IN VS2022 command prompt it's called **guidgen**

Comment: This should not be marked correct, as most users do not have the SDK. Calling powershell from cmd is the way to go, as various answers below describe.

Answer (score 32):

Try this if you have powershell environment.

```
FOR /F %a IN ('POWERSHELL -COMMAND "$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"') DO ( SET NEWGUID=%a )
```

Then ready Guid value from `%NEWGUID%`

Comment: If writing a batch file (`.bat`), don't forget to double the `%` in the `FOR` statement (so the line should read `FOR /F %%a IN ('POWERSHELL -COMMAND "$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"') DO ( SET NEWGUID=%%a )`)

Comment: @Soundararajan powershell and .NET is available in all Windows versions since Vista

Answer (score 29):

easy to do in powershell

```
[guid]::NewGuid()
```

Comment: Even easier now: [`New-Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-guid)

Answer (score 26):

1.Create a file named  myuuid.vbs with the content

```
set obj = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")  
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Mid(obj.GUID, 2, 36)
```

2.goto command prompt

`cscript //NoLogo myuuid.vbs`

Using  JAVA code

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
```

Comment: @Pratik this is VB Script code that will do your task you don't need any special env for this just follow 2 steps mentioned

Comment: @Pratik have you followed step 2 exactly mentioned ? from command line it should be "script //NoLogo myuuid.vbs  "

Comment: @Pratik type "cscript //NoLogo myuuid.vbs"

Comment: @Pratik http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject.html here is example how to create file using VBS and it is already stored in variable OBJ , I am not much aware about VBS otherwise I would have told you :)

Comment: Install cygwin, and ensure you have the _util-linux_ package. That will give you a `uuidgen` command.

Answer (score 13):

This will copy a new GUID to your clipboard:

```
POWERSHELL -c "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper()" | CLIP
```

Recent versions have cmdlets like this:

```
POWERSHELL -c "New-Guid | Set-Clipboard"
```

Answer (score 11):

There is no built-in command available that does that. Either write your own, or get an existing one.

A simple program that outputs a GUID to the console could be written using C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

Place the above snippet in a file name guidgen.cs and then compile it using the following command line (.NET Framework 2.0 would have to be installed on your system):

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe guidgen.cs
```

This will create an executable named `guidgen.exe`.

Comment: seems like C#. well i have an very old pc with no .NET framwork will this work or do you some solution other than this ?

Comment: @Pratik: How old? Is it really running MS-DOS? Do you have any compiler available at all?

Comment: dos version 5.1.2600 on Windows XP. i don't have any idea about compilers

Comment: Any idea why I'm not able to `clip` the output in bash as `$ guidgen | clip`? I'm having to wrap this in a function and export it as `guidgen() { echo "$(guidgen.exe)"; }
export -f guidgen` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500499/how-do-you-call-a-function-defined-in-bashrc-from-the-shell/1500592#1500592).

Comment: The ToString call is not necessary as WriteLine has an overload for System.Object, which does the same. Not sure if creating the string instance is worse than boxing performance-wise, but it certainly is longer and less readable.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it with pure cmd commands, you can use something like that (this is not a true GUID but it can help depending on your context) :

```
@call :GetGuid NewGuid
@echo My new GUID : %NewGuid%

@goto :eof


:GetGuid
 @set _guid=%computername%%date%%time%
 @set _guid=%_guid:/=%
 @set _guid=%_guid:.=%
 @set _guid=%_guid: =%
 @set _guid=%_guid:,=%
 @set _guid=%_guid::=%
 @set _guid=%_guid:-=%
 @set %1=%_guid%
@goto :eof
```

Comment: Save the contents as a .BAT file and run it.  Works on my machine (Windows 8).

Comment: Better to do it in a .CMD file to be interpreted by CMD.EXE instead of COMMAND.COM ;-) http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-cmd-and-bat/

Comment: why don't just put `@echo off` at the beginning instead of prefixing every commands with `@`?

Comment: Prefixing every commands with a @ is useful when you are debugging your script. If you suspect that a line is not running well, just suppress the @ for this line and re-run your script. You will see at the console what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

try with [uuid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/uuid.bat)
Without arguments it will just echo the generated `uuid`:

```
c:\>uuid.bat

2186cb38-d649-4c99-b7cc-c505e4dae9c2
```

If argument is passed it will be stored in a variable with the same name:

```
call uuid.bat my_uuid
echo %my_uuid%
```

> 94772f66-8bca-468e-9e9a-de0d9ee05cc1

For windows formatted GUIDs you can use [guid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/guid.bat):

```
for /f %a in ('guid.bat') do set guid=%a
echo %guid%
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `dotnet` installed:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g guid
$ guid
bf4be9d0-7d1b-485c-a435-d07fd7b892f0
$ guid help
Usage:

    guid [option]

Where [option] is an optional single character that controls formatting:

    N    B382C3F44E604D08B48A2D342A659B4E
    D    B382C3F4-4E60-4D08-B48A-2D342A659B4E
    B    {B382C3F4-4E60-4D08-B48A-2D342A659B4E}
    P    (B382C3F4-4E60-4D08-B48A-2D342A659B4E)

When unspecified, 'd' formatting is used. Use lowercase [option] for lowercase output.
```

Answer (score 2):

One could abuse `bitsadmin` to generate a GUID.  This will be profoundly faster than calling PowerShell from a Batch script.

```bat
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "delims={}" %%I in ('bitsadmin /rawreturn /create guid') do set "GUID=%%~I"
>NUL bitsadmin /cancel {%GUID%}

echo Your new GUID is %GUID%.  Neat.
```

If you want to keep the surrounding braces, remove `"delims={}"` and replace `{%GUID%}` with `%GUID%`.

Answer (score 0):

If the system OS does not have Windows SDK but does have a C compiler with mingw-w64 toolchain then compile this small program to generate random GUID. Imported functions are [UuidCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate) (rpcrt4.lib) to create random UUID and [StringFromCLSID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-stringfromclsid) (ole32.lib) to convert UUID to wide string.

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * int UuidCreate(GUID *id);
 * int StringFromCLSID(GUID *id, wchar_t **str);
 * Libraries: Rpcrt4.lib Ole32.lib
 */

int main(void)
{
    GUID id;
    wchar_t *str = NULL;

    UuidCreate(&id);
    StringFromCLSID(&id, &str);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", str);
}
```