# how to Generate a random number in CMD that is not based on system clock

Tags: batch-file, random, cmd, systemtime

I want to create a random number in a batch file, that is not based on the system clock time.

I have been trying to use `%RANDOM%` but its not working well for my needs.

The reason is that I want to write file names that I'm recieving in muliple threads to files, and when I use the system time `%RANDOM%` method I get clashes between the files, since the system time is based on seconds and not milliseconds.

So I need a way to generate random number based on something else other than system time...

Comment: if you have reliable internet connection you can query random.org

Comment: thanks, great idea, unfortunately my system running the code is an offline server :)

Comment: Do you need to create a _random number_ or [unique file name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27802376/3439404)?

Comment: @npocmaka, don't we have a thread on dostips about different random number algorithms.  Trying to find it right now.

Comment: [wmic os get localdatetime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18024049/2152082) gives you a date/time string with a ms-resolution. If this is sufficcient and timing is not a problem (`wmic` is quite slow), you could use a date/time-string instead of a random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issues is that your running multiple threads, couldn't you give each batch file a 'unique ID' variable for every different thread (e.g. `id`) and append that to the end of `%random%` to generate a different number for each one. E.g:

```
::: Call your batch files with a unique parameter for each thread (e.g. "prog.bat 1")
set id=%%1
::: Alternatively if you're starting each thread at a different time:
:: set id=%random%

:: Later in the batch file when you're writing a file
echo %random%%id%
:: ^ a unique random number for each thread
```

If the multiple threads are you're only problem this should work.

Comment: thing is that i have hundred of threads working simultaneously and automatically, launches from a single process

Comment: This method should still work, as long as the single process launching it assigns each thread a different ID.

Comment: thats true, but the process is 3rd party , and cant generate id when launching the batch file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have threads, then add a random generator thread which provides random numbers to the other threads as needed.  Have a single RNG running in that thread which is initialised once only from the clock.  Other threads call on the random generator thread to get the next random number in the sequence.

The clock is only used once, when the random thread starts, so the problem of time clashes should not arise as long as the random thread runs for more than one second.

If necessary those other threads can use their single random number to seed their own RNGs to generate more numbers.

Comment: that might work, but its too complex for a dos batch :)

Comment: even when the clocks don't match there is a chance for collisions, although reduced, as you can receive the same number again.